# How? indent user input in a search_field

Tags: css

When users enter text into the search_field I want it to start 4 spaces to the right so that the text does not display over/under the search icon in the box. I basically want my search_field_tag to work just like itunes search bar (when you type the text displays to the right of the icon). Appreciate any assistance.

Have to modify the text within the search field thus this code makes it work.

Needed CSS:

```
.search-query {
text-indent: 15px;
}
```

Current code:

```
<%= form_tag users_path, :method => 'get', :class => "navbar-search" do %>
<%= search_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "    Find Members", :class => "search-query", :style => "width: 100px" %>
<div class="icon-search"></div>
<% end %>
```

CSS

```
.navbar-search .icon-search {
position: absolute;
top: 4px;
left: 7px;
```

[image: Search Bar]
[image: Search with problem]

Comment: I can't properly make out which you want, but this is done with either `padding-left:` or `text-indent:`

Comment: Still not working. I just want user input in my text_field to start a little to the right. itunes does this. Twitter search bar also doesn't let the text hit the icon but theirs is to the right. I need two more rep points and i can upload pictures

Comment: Just for future reference, it's really frustrating when you post pre-compiled code. ASP code does not help, show us the resultant HTML that is printed onto the webpage, thats where the magic happens.

Comment: right sorry Im new to this stuff. Anyways thanks I needed text-indent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.search-query {
  text-indent: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add padding in your textarea using css as you required!

```
.navbar-search .icon-search {
position: absolute;
top: 4px;
left: 7px;
padding-left:20px; // this applies to only left and will start the text 20px away from the left side of textarea or input
}
```

Comment: I need padding on the text within the textbox not the text_field itself

Comment: my answer above doing nothin?

Comment: For some reason even with the padding the text starting point doesn't change. something conflicting?

Answer (score 0):

Place the icon as a background image in the .navbar-search and add padding-left to position the type. See below.

```
   .navbar-search {
    padding-left: 25px; // set to any px* of choice
    background: <set background color> url('<path to an image(preferably .png)>') no-repeat 0 0;
   }
```

*What ever amount of padding-left is given to the search bar will affect its width.